# jquery append svg element, unable to append more than one element

Tags: jquery, svg

I am trying to use JQuery to append some svg elements. Code as shown below.

```
$("#save_edits").click(function() {

    var img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
        img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','./img/exclamation-mark.png');
        img.setAttributeNS(null,'x','-7');
        img.setAttributeNS(null,'y','-35');
        img.setAttributeNS(null,'height','15');
        img.setAttributeNS(null,'width','15');

    if(id==" Shipping"){
        $('svg>g').first().append(img);
        $('svg>g:eq(2)').append(img);
        $('svg>g:eq(3)').append(img);
        $('svg>g:eq(4)').append(img);
    }
});
```

However, only the last append works successfully `$('svg>g:eq(4)').append(img);`, and not all the previous. Does anyone know why previous ones were override and how to prevent it from occurring?

**Answer:**
Ok, seems like I figured out eventually. Basically need to recreate the img element again for each append.

```
child = ["svg>g:eq(2)","svg>g:eq(3)","svg>g:eq(4)"]

if(id==" Shipping"){
    child.forEach(function(e){
        var img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
            img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','./img/exclamation-mark.png');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'x','-7');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'y','-35');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'height','15');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'width','15');

        $(e).append(img);
    })
```

Comment: I think you're expecting it to be a clone each time you append and it's not.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: how many svg you are using

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta just one

Comment: ok, i resolved it, thanks too all for helping!